# Getting the raphael id attribute in the DOM

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have converted some SVG to Rapahel using http://readysetraphael.com/

Here is an example of code produced:

```
...
path6233.attr({id: 'path6233' 
...
```

I have looked in the attr document and it doesn't mention id as a proper attribute. Neither is the id attribute added to the DOM. Is there some way to make raphael add this ID to the DOM so that I can style the element?

Alternatively, can I somehow walk all the paths and add move the id attr to a real DOM ID easily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hadn't seen readysetraphael.com before -- that's pretty nifty.

It should be reasonably straightforward to walk all of the elements inside a given SVG container via the Raphael paper element's forEach method:

```
var i = 0;
paper.forEach(function (el) 
{
    el.node.setAttribute("id", "node-" + i++ ) );
});
```

But I should ask -- since you already have your SVGs incorporated into Raphael, why wouldn't you simply use Raphael to style them programmatically?  Curiosity about your reasoning prompts me to ask.

Comment: That's a good question. I guess I'm used to thinking that style should be separate from code logic. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I know what you mean.  If only Raphael allowed application of css classes to the underlying nodes attributes...  but all the evidence I've seen indicates it won't work with external stylesheet.  Here's hoping Raphael 3.0 addresses that!

Comment: Ok. I'm new to Raphael and will keep this in mind. Your feedback was very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can do so by fetching the shapes underlying DOM element, with a call to the `node` property, like so:

```js
path6233.node.id = 'node-id';
```