# can't change the fill color in Raphael?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm trying to change the circle color from green to red but i can't here. After long time research i found one issue, which is when i use class in Raphael i can't change the color.
i need to use the class to change the color of the cirle.

```
var paper = new Raphael('myPaper',500,500);

var SCircle = paper.circle(300,100,50).data('id','green');
SCircle.node.setAttribute('class','green'); 

$("#test").click(function () {   
    SCircle.animate({fill:'pink'},200); //color is not filling
} )
```

Here is the [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Amb9b/14/)

Any suggestions should be appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be css precedence. The css class takes precedence over the fill during the animate call. Read this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847481/getting-the-raphael-id-attribute-in-the-dom) for more discussion which advises not using CSS styles for styling Raphael objects.

Applying the attributes explicitly without css works.

```
var paper = new Raphael('myPaper',500,500);    
var SCircle = paper.circle(300,100,50); 
SCircle.node.setAttribute('fill','green');
SCircle.node.setAttribute('stroke','black');
SCircle.node.setAttribute('stroke-width','3');

$("#test").click(function() {   
    SCircle.animate({'fill':'pink'},200);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to use class because i need to change the css by class only. How to use the classes and how to override it.

Comment: I'll investigate - I'd like to know myself if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

`setAttribute` is known to be buggy for DOM attributes in some browsers. Try the simple `className` attribute instead:

```
SCircle.node.className = 'green';
```

This is known to work in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks, but its also not working. when i use like this the class is not applied.

Comment: Your JSFiddle works. The circle is green in my browser. I modified the code to use the className I suggested and it works as well. Both works. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do this without using the **`node`** and maybe avoiding `css`. Look at the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Amb9b/21/)**:

```
var paper = new Raphael('myPaper',500,500);

var SCircle = paper.circle(300,100,50).data('id','green');
SCircle.attr({fill: 'green', stroke: '#000', "stroke-width": 3}); 

$("#test").click(function () {   
    SCircle.animate({fill:'pink'},200); //good to go
} )
```